# My code (in another file) somehow gets triggered in a different file (discord.js, node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a ban command that bans a user yada yada.. But, somehow, a different command in a different file gets triggered. (I use a command handler).

This is the `switch` statement in `index.js`:

```
bot.on("message", message => {
    let args = message.content.substring(botconfig.prefix.length).split(" ")

    switch (args[0]) {
        case "ban":
            bot.commands.get('ban').execute(message, args)

        case "unban":
            bot.commands.get('unban').execute(message, args)
    }
})
```

This is `ban.js` (the file that triggers `unban.js`)

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const botconfig = require("../botconfig.json")
const ms = require("ms")

module.exports = {
    name: 'ban',
    description: 'Bans a user from your server.',
    execute(message, args) {

        let bannedUser = message.mentions.members.first()
        let banDuration;
        let banReason;

        const noPermsEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(":x: You do not have permission to perform this command!")
            .setColor(botconfig.colors.err)

        const UserDoesNotExistEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(":warning: This user is not a member of this server.")
            .setColor(botconfig.colors.warn)

        const banEmbedReason = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`You are about to ban ${bannedUser.user.username}, first pick a reason for the ban.`)
            .setDescription("Please pick a reason for your ban first")
            .addFields({ name: ':regional_indicator_a: Use of bad language', value: 'Ban the user for use of inappropriate language in the server' }, { name: ':regional_indicator_b: Insulting a member', value: 'Ban the user for insulting memebers on the server for any reason' }, { name: ':regional_indicator_c: Spamming in the server', value: 'Ban the user for spamming messages on the server' }, { name: ':regional_indicator_d: NSFW/harmful/inappropriate content', value: 'Ban the user for sending inappropriate content on the server' }, { name: ':regional_indicator_e: Other..', value: 'For a differnet reason, write the reason in chat, like "$banreason <reason>"' }, { name: ':x: None', value: '\u200b' }, )
            .setColor(botconfig.colors.err)

        const banEmbedDuration = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`Now, please pick a duration for the ban`)
            .setDescription("Please pick a duration for your ban first")
            .addFields({ name: ':regional_indicator_a: 1 day', value: '\u200b' }, { name: ':regional_indicator_b: 3 days', value: '\u200b' }, { name: ':regional_indicator_c: 7 days', value: '\u200b' }, { name: ':regional_indicator_d: 14 days', value: '\u200b' }, { name: ':regional_indicator_e: 28 days', value: '\u200b' }, { name: ':infinity: Forever', value: '\u200b' }, )
            .setColor(botconfig.colors.err)

        if (!message.member.hasPermission(['BAN_MEMBERS']) || bannedUser.hasPermission(['MANAGE_GUILD'])) {
            message.channel.send(noPermsEmbed)
            return
        }

        if (!message.guild.member(bannedUser)) {
            message.channel.send(UserDoesNotExistEmbed)
            return
        }

        message.channel.send({ embed: banEmbedReason }).then(embedMessage => {

            // GETS TRIGGERED HERE

            const reasonFilter = (reaction, user) => {
                return ['', '', '', '', '❌'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
            };

            embedMessage.react("")
                .then(() => embedMessage.react(""))
                .then(() => embedMessage.react(""))
                .then(() => embedMessage.react(""))
                .then(() => embedMessage.react("❌"))
                .then(() => {
                    embedMessage.awaitReactions(reasonFilter, { max: 1, time: 120000 }).then(collected => {

                        const otherCollector = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, m => m.author.id === message.author.id, { time: 60000 });
                        otherCollector.on('collect', msg => {
                            if (msg.content.startsWith(`${botconfig.prefix}banreason`)) {
                                banReason = msg.content
                            }
                        })

                        const reasonReaction = collected.first()

                        if (reasonReaction.emoji.name === '') {
                            banReason = "Use of bad language"
                        } else if (reasonReaction.emoji.name === '') {
                            banReason = "Insulting a member"
                        } else if (reasonReaction.emoji.name === '') {
                            banReason = "Spamming in the server"
                        } else if (reasonReaction.emoji.name === '') {
                            banReason = "NSFW/harmful/inappropriate content"
                        } else if (reasonReaction.emoji.name === '❌') {
                            banReason = "None specified"
                        }

                        message.channel.send({ embed: banEmbedDuration }).then(embedMessage => {

                            const durationFilter = (reaction, user) => {
                                return ['', '', '', '', '', '♾️'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
                            };

                            embedMessage.react("")
                                .then(() => embedMessage.react(""))
                                .then(() => embedMessage.react(""))
                                .then(() => embedMessage.react(""))
                                .then(() => embedMessage.react(""))
                                .then(() => embedMessage.react("♾️"))
                                .then(() => {
                                    embedMessage.awaitReactions(durationFilter, { max: 1, time: 120000 }).then(collected => {

                                            const durationReaction = collected.first()

                                            if (durationReaction.emoji.name === '') {
                                                banDuration = 1
                                            } else if (durationReaction.emoji.name === '') {
                                                banDuration = 3
                                            } else if (durationReaction.emoji.name === '') {
                                                banDuration = 7
                                            } else if (durationReaction.emoji.name === '') {
                                                banDuration = 14
                                            } else if (durationReaction.emoji.name === '') {
                                                banDuration = 28
                                            } else if (durationReaction.emoji.name === '♾️') {
                                                banDuration = 0 //infinite
                                            }

                                        })
                                        .then(() => {

                                            const banConfirmation = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                                .setTitle(`You sucessfully banned ${bannedUser.user.username}.`)
                                                .setDescription(`You have sucessfuly banned ${bannedUser} from the server.`)
                                                .addFields({ name: ':timer: Ban duration:', value: `${banDuration} days. (0 days = forever)` }, { name: ':page_with_curl: Ban reason:', value: `"${banReason}"` })
                                                .setColor(botconfig.colors.success)

                                            bannedUser.ban({ days: 7, reason: banReason }).catch(err => {
                                                console.log(err)
                                                message.channel.send(`An error occured: ${err}`)
                                            })

                                            message.channel.send({ embed: banConfirmation })

                                            if (banDuration == 0) {} else {

                                                console.log('Starting countdown untill ban ends.')

                                                setTimeout(() => {
                                                    message.guild.members.unban(bannedUser, "The ban duration has passed.")
                                                }, ms(`${banDuration}d`))
                                            }
                                        })
                                })

                        })

                    })

                })
        })

    }
}
```

This is the file that get unban `unban.js`:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const botconfig = require("../botconfig.json")

module.exports = {
    name: 'unban',
    description: 'Unban a user from the server',
    execute(message, args) {

        let unbannedUser = message.mentions.members.first()

        const confirmEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`:white_check_mark: You have sucessfully unbanned ${unbannedUser.user.username}.`)
            .setColor(botconfig.colors.success)

        const errEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`:x: A problem occcured while trying to unbaning ${unbannedUser.user.username}.`)
            .setColor(botconfig.colors.err)

        try {

            // THIS GETS TRIGGERED    
  
            message.guild.members.unban(unbannedUser)
            message.channel.send({ embed: confirmEmbed })
        } catch (e) {
            message.channel.send({ embed: errEmbed })
        }
    }
}
```

This is the result: (when the first message gets sent it sends the message that says you ubnanned someone right after it, which is in a different file(?))

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is because you haven't added `break` to your `switch` statement.

```js
bot.on("message", message => {
    let args = message.content.substring(botconfig.prefix.length).split(" ")

    switch (args[0]) {
        case "ban":
            bot.commands.get('ban').execute(message, args)
            break

        case "unban":
            bot.commands.get('unban').execute(message, args)
    }
})
```

If you omit the break statement, the next case will be executed even if the evaluation does not match the case.
It is not necessary to break the last case in a switch block. The block breaks (ends) there anyway.